# Filter xml with LINQ2XML

Tags: .net, linq

I'm a newbie with LINQ2XML. I'm trying to filter an xml file and get another xml with the results. I want to filter by the value of some attributes.

The xml looks like this (abreviated version, the actual version has more nodes and attributes):

```
<Root>
    <Group Price="50">
       <Item Price="60"/>
       <Item Price="50"/>
       <Item Price="70"/>
    </Group>
    <Group Price="55">
       <Item Price="62"/>
       <Item Price="57"/>
       <Item Price="55"/>
    </Group>
    <Group Price="61">
       <Item Price="62"/>
       <Item Price="61"/>
       <Item Price="65"/>
    </Group>
    <!--More Group Nodes--> 
</Root>
```

Now let's suppose I want nodes with value whose price is lower than 60. What I want to get is:
I've removed nodes with prices 60, 70 and 62. EDIT: I want to remove Group Node with price 61 (it doesn't fullfill the condition).

```
<Root>
    <Group Price="50">
       <Item Price="50"/>
    </Group>
    <Group Price="55">
       <Item Price="57"/>
       <Item Price="55"/>
    </Group>
    <!--More Group Nodes--> 
</Root>
```

Or maybe is there any way to remove nodes what don't fullfill the conditions? Thanks for your answers.

PS: I'd like to know if this can be done using XPATH too. I post it in another question:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the nodes to remove then remove them.

```
var filterPrice = 60M;
var removeMe =
    from item in doc.Descendants("Item")
    where (decimal)item.Attribute("Price") >= filterPrice
    select item;
removeMe.Remove();
```

Or using XPath:

```
var filterPrice = 60M;
var xpath = String.Format("//Item[@Price>={0}]", filterPrice);
var removeMe = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
removeMe.Remove();
```

Combined to remove groups too:

```
var filterItemPrice = 60M;
var filterGroupPrice = 60M;
var removeGroups =
    from grp in doc.Descendants("Group")
    where (decimal)grp.Attribute("Price") >= filterGroupPrice
    select grp;
var removeItems =
    from item in doc.Descendants("Item")
    where (decimal)item.Attribute("Price") >= filterItemPrice
    select item;
var removeMe = removeItems.Concat(removeGroups);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested it and it works. If I'd want to remove group nodes what don't fullfill the conditions could it be done in one only sentence or I have to do it in two steps (First remove group nodes and then item nodes)?

Comment: Sure you could combine them into a single statement. Fortunately both contain the same-named attribute to test so you could combine the selectors. Otherwise you could select both sets separately and concatenate them together.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. So far I've got it in two steps. Now I'd like to get the xml orderer by the attribute price. Ordering Group Nodes and then Item nodes. I've posted another question in: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011941/order-xml-file-using-linq2xml> Thanks for helping me in my first steps with LINQ and XPath.