# Order xml file using linq2xml

Tags: .net, xpath, linq-to-xml

Following question [Filter xml with LINQ2XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006160/filter-xml-with-linq2xml)

After succesfully filtering (removing nodes) from a xml file. I'd like to order by some attribute in nodes.

Sample of xml file:

```
<Root> 
   <Group Price="50"> 
       <Item Price="60"/> 
       <Item Price="50"/> 
       <Item Price="70"/> 
   </Group> 
   <Group Price="55"> 
       <Item Price="62"/> 
       <Item Price="57"/> 
       <Item Price="55"/> 
   </Group> 
   <Group Price="61"> 
       <Item Price="62"/> 
       <Item Price="61"/> 
       <Item Price="65"/> 
    </Group> 
    <!--More Group Nodes-->  
</Root>
```

And I'd like to get:

```
<Root> 
   <Group Price="61"> 
       <Item Price="65"/> 
       <Item Price="62"/> 
       <Item Price="61"/> 
    </Group> 
    <Group Price="55"> 
       <Item Price="62"/> 
       <Item Price="57"/> 
       <Item Price="55"/> 
   </Group> 
   <Group Price="50"> 
       <Item Price="70"/> 
       <Item Price="60"/> 
       <Item Price="50"/> 
   </Group> 
   <!--More Group Nodes-->  
</Root>
```

My current code is (Mix LINQ2Xml and XPATH):

```
'First I remove Group nodes with prices higher than 60 (and their sons).

dim filter as String="./Root/Group[not(translate(@Price, ',.', '.')<=60})]"

elements = doc.XPathSelectElements(filter).OrderByDescending((Function(x) CType(x.Attribute("Price"), Decimal)))

'Remove elements what don't fullfill the condition  (prices higher than 60)                   
elements.Remove()

'After I remove Item nodes with prices higher than 60

filter as String="./Root/Group/Item[not(translate(@Price, ',.', '.')<=60})]"

elements = doc.XPathSelectElements(filter).OrderByDescending((Function(x) CType(x.Attribute("Price"), Decimal)))

'Remove elements what don't fullfill the condition  (prices higher than 60)
 elements.Remove()
```

As I said before, I'm filtering succesfully but I'm not able to order (descending in this case).
Is there any way to order Group Nodes and Item nodes in one step or I have to do it in two steps?

Someone told me about using replaceNodes of XDocument but I  don't get any results.

Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: Please explain in plain English what you want to achieve. Do you want to order the `Group` elements by their `Price` attribute value? Which elements do you want to remove, `Group` elements or `Item` elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the group descending then you can use LINQ and OrderByDescending.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Root>  <Group Price=\"50\">  <Item Price=\"60\"/>  <Item    Price=\"50\"/>  <Item Price=\"70\"/>  </Group>  <Group Price=\"55\">  <Item Price=\"62\"/>  <Item Price=\"57\"/>  <Item Price=\"55\"/>  </Group>  <Group Price=\"61\">  <Item Price=\"62\"/>  <Item Price=\"61\"/> <Item Price=\"65\"/>  </Group>  <!--More Group Nodes-->   </Root>  ");

IEnumerable<XElement> list = doc.Elements()
                                .Elements("Group")
                                .OrderByDescending(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Attribute("Price").Value));
```